# NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password/reset/confirm

Tags: django

I am using django userena and getting the error.After submitting the email address for password reset,i am getting a pass reset confirmation mail.The mail body is something like this

```
You're receiving this e-mail because you requested a password reset
for your user account at example.example.com.

Please go to the following page and choose a new password:

http://example.example.com/accounts/password/reset/confirm/Mg-3xm-add2c70e92d3694c5043/



Your username, in case you've forgotten: ****


Thanks for using our site!

Sincerely,
example.example.com
```

but after clicking the link to chooise a new password, i am getting the following error

```
NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password/reset/confirm/Mg-3xm-add2c70e92d3694c5043/
Reverse for 'password_reset_complete' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not    found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://med.finder-lbs.com/accounts/password/reset/confirm/Mg-3xm-   add2c70e92d3694c5043/
Django Version: 1.6.1
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'password_reset_complete' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not     found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^resetpassword/passwordsent/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done', name='password_reset_done'),
url(r'^password/reset/$',
   auth_views.password_reset,
   {'template_name': 'userena/password_reset_form.html',
    'email_template_name': 'userena/emails/password_reset_message.txt',
    'extra_context': {'without_usernames': userena_settings.USERENA_WITHOUT_USERNAMES}
    },
   name='userena_password_reset'),
url(r'^password/reset/done/$',
   auth_views.password_reset_done,
   {'template_name': 'userena/password_reset_done.html'},
   name='userena_password_reset_done'),
url(r'^user/password/reset/confirm/$',
         'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm'),
url(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
   auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
   {'template_name': 'userena/password_reset_confirm_form.html'},
   name='userena_password_reset_confirm'),

url(r'^password/reset/confirm/complete/$',
   auth_views.password_reset_complete,
   {'template_name': 'userena/password_reset_complete.html'}),
```

**password_reset_message.txt**

```
{% load i18n %}{% autoescape off %}{% load url from future %}
{% blocktrans %}You're receiving this e-mail because you,requested a password reset
for your user account at {{ site_name }}{% endblocktrans %}.

{% trans "Please go to the following page and choose a new password:" %}
{% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'userena_password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid   token=token %}
{% endblock %}

{% if not without_usernames %}{% blocktrans with user.username as username %}
Your username, in case you've forgotten: {{ username }}
{% endblocktrans %}
{% endif %}
{% trans "Thanks for using our site!" %}

{% trans "Sincerely" %},
{{ site_name }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

i am pretty sure something missing here but i can't figure it out.I am using django 1.6

Comment: Why did you change the URL again?

Comment: no i have changed it previously @BurhanKhalid

Comment: From where did you get this `urls.py`?

Comment: BurhanKhalid,don't get it wrong and don't be confuused ,i have edited my post.The url was edited previously,i had just mentioned it at the end of my post,i have removed that portion already @BurhanKhalid

Comment: Are you sure? This is [not the `urls.py` that comes with userena](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/urls.py). I believe you have not setup your project correctly because you should not have to edit or modify this file in any way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67186/discussion-between-rego-and-burhan-khalid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# urls.py
url(r'^password/reset/confirm/complete/$',
   auth_views.password_reset_complete,
   {'template_name': 'userena/password_reset_complete.html'},
   name='password_reset_complete') # must be named for reverse to work
```

Naming the url should solve your NoReverseMatch error.

However, it sounds like you may have another issue, because you describe this error as occurring immediately after you click the reset link, which means that the `password_reset_confirm` view is trying to redirect the user to `password_reset_complete` immediately - not after they've chosen a new password.

Comment: its not working according to your answer,btw what type issue do you think  that occurring  the error?can you please help me?i am stuck in this matter.

Comment: If that didn't solve the problem (or change the error you get), your urls.py is not being picked up by your application.

Comment: do you talking about the whole urls.py file or the particular url? @Enrico

Comment: @Rego It could be either

Comment: my urls.py file surely picked up by the application,because i have set up the urls for the sign in and sign up in this same urls.py file,and sign up and sign in functionality working absolutely fine. @Enrico

Comment: Sorry I had a typo in my answer. That url should be named `password_reset_complete` not `_confirm`.